# Helping for identifying LCD board (and its datasheet) extracted from APC USP

Tags: identification, components, lcd

I removed this board from a broke APS USP. I want to use it for other projects but I don't know its protocols. I googled the part number but the information I found was mostly unhelpful.

I really appreciate any help.

[image: LCD BOARD BACK]

[image: LCD BOARD FRONT]

Comment: You don't say what help you need. That board is likely a custom part so no way to know what chip it has and what pinout it has based on part number label. Connect it back to host system and start analyzing the pinout and protocol if it matches an existing protocol.

Comment: The board is a version of BMX-01 E226252 CBS058A03-00 Board U but I couldn't find the pinouts for that one either.

Comment: As was suggested above: the most practical way to figure out how to drive this board is by having a working UPS and looking at the signals. If you tell us the UPS model, I can go to a store and buy one and see what’s there. Hopefully they didn’t overcomplicate it.

Comment: This display would be most useful if it was fully graphical. If it’s just some custom-laid segments and not a dot matrix, then its utility drops somewhat. But still it could be of some use. I expect the physical layer to be SPI or I2C, and simple commands for updating display contents and reading the button status. There may be a separate interrupt line to signal when a button is pressed so the main CPU won’t have to constantly poll the buttons.

Comment: If it is a dot matrix then a more typical nibble protocol and discrete wires for the buttons make more sense, given the number of pins on the connector.

Comment: thanks @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica! I'm trying to extract firmware from the UPS device to see how it communicates with the display.